# prevent animation from occurring when initially binding

Tags: wpf, animation, binding

I have a 2nd stackpanel that appears like a drawer, shown below

```
 ______               ______ _____
|      |             |      |     |
| main |     ->      | main | 2nd |
|______|             |______|_____|
                              -->
```

I have both expand and collapse animations for the drawer.  They are bound to a boolean that I update in code.

Everything works fine, except when I initially start my application, the collapse animation gets fired because the initial value is false.  Is there a way to bind something without it triggering upon binding?

Here is what is looks like in my xaml, where I am using a DataTrigger bound to the boolen thats in my code:

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="expandMe" Width="0" Orientation="Vertical" >
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExpandBoolean}" Value="False">
                            .......
```

Comment: Is there a problem setting the init value to true?

Comment: Well, that would perform the expand animation rather than the collapse animation on start.  Ideally, I want it to start closed (false), without executing the animation that is bound to it being false

Comment: have you tried adding animation after you loaded the control? that might do the trick

Comment: looks like a fun puzzle, can you post your code? I'll play with it and get it to work (hopefully)

Comment: It would be too much to post, but I posted the part of the xaml where i bind to the datatrigger.  Not sure if I could really "hold off" on the binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the Setter in your style to make sure that the StackPanel loads collapsed. I think that will do it.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="expandMe" Width="0" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value "Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExpandBoolean}" Value="False">
```

Comment: Sweet, that did it.  I just had to add another Setter inside of the "True" DataTrigger that set the Visibility back to Visible. Thanks!